# How to do xml serilization for derived entity

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, ixmlserializable

```
public abstract class Base
{
    //abstract methods
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    //method implementations
}

public class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    //method implementations
}
```

I am doing serilization with "Derived2"

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Derived2));
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize);
```

It gives exception for `Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.` and `unable to generate xmldocument`

Now, problem is, I can't include xmlinclude attribute on parent entities as I do not have any control on parent entities. I have full control on most derived entity `derived2`.

Any solution to achieve serialization for this.

Comment: Given an instance of `Derived2`, the above code works just fine: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Derived2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />` so can you create an example that fails?

Comment: above example is failing, have instance of  `Derived2` and  doing `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Derived2)); serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize); //this line is getting failed.`

Comment: even adding - xmlinclude too its not working.

Comment: Seems to be working in LinqPad - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vHbd.png

Comment: here problem is weird, when I post data and use object to seriliaze then it gives me this exception, but writing `new Derived2()` is working fine. I am posting data from PostMan (web api) and just doing serilization. and it fails due to above error.